# Control Position Of Added Worksheet

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, vsto

I have a workbook that has roughly 32 worksheets in it, I am using C# to add a new worksheet, and it always adds the worksheet at the end, and I would like for the worksheet to be added as the 2nd worksheet.  Is it possible to control the positioning of the added worksheet?

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, xlWorkBook.Worksheets[xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count], System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
xlWorkSheet.Name = "Added through code";
```

Comment: try `xlWorkSheet.Move(Missing.Value, xlWorkBook.Sheets[1]);`

Comment: @AlexK. - I get a compile error of 'The name 'Missing' does not exist in the current context'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Worksheets.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838966.aspx) takes four parameters: Before, After, Count, and Type.

You're passing in the "After" parameter as the final worksheet, which is why it's being added at the end.

To add the new worksheet in a specific place, you have to specify where.

If you want it to be the second worksheet, pass the first worksheet as the "After" parameter:

```
xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
      xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1], // worksheets are 1 based
      System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
      System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Or you could it add it after a named worksheet:

```
xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
      xlWorkBook.Worksheets["sheet1"],
      System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
      System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Comment: This is much better than .Moveing it.

Comment: I get an error of Invalid Index.  Does that mean it is 1 based?

Comment: [Yes it is](http://superuser.com/questions/988321/which-excel-objects-are-zero-based-and-which-are-one-based)